# How to make a static right sidebar with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I'm working on http://tosamaganga.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/option1.html, and I want to create a fixed-responsive sidebar on the right side using Bootstrap.

I'm using this "2 Columns" Bootstrap class, but this is not what I need:

```
<!-- Start 2 Columns -->
<div class="col-md-8">
    <p align="left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 
        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
        irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
        pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <ul class="list_yes">
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
            <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa.</li>
            <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <ul>
        <li class="option_list"> <a href="option2.html">Option 2</a></li>
        <li class="option_list"><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>   
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <p align="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    <ul class="list_yes">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
      <li>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa.</li>
      <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li class="option_list"> <a href="option2.html">Option 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="option_list"><a href="#">Option 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar{
 position: fixed;
}
```